# Can you use Craft to build a relational web app database in a Knapp or Caspio style?

Tags: database, relations

I guess the answer is probably "No" but I have read this "relate anything to anything" feature here http://buildwithcraft.com/features/relations and I was wondering how powerful is that.

I want to create an Events website

In my project users should be able to:

- Enter records via a form (Events)
- Change their own records
- Choose an event and say they attend it (subscribe)
- Enter or choose how the travel to that event (by car, bus, plane)
- To rate and add a comment to those events.

The Events should show for instance how many people attend to that event, who are those people and how they travel there.

Ideally users should be able to sell their own even tickets but that will need some custom developing for implementation.

I could reach that kind of functionality with an SaaS database online solution like knapp or Caspio, create their a relational database and embed their database views in a CMS like Craft but I would prefer to use just Craft for the whole project.

Would be that possible to build all that in Craft?

Comment: I do not know enough to give you a proper answer but I would say it is perfectly possible. You would probably need a channel for the events and perhaps a separate channel for interactions on the event (ratings, comments etc). You can use Guest Editions or create your own plugin to add entries via a form.

Comment: @Shane I'd up vote your post if it was an actual answer!

Answer (score 4):

It is perfectly possible. You would probably need a channel for the events and perhaps a separate channel for interactions on the event (ratings, comments etc). You can use Guest Editions or create your own plugin to add entries via a form.

Comment: Okay turning my comment into an answer, will try to extend it later.